# Task manager shows high CPU but 'user' shows differently

Tags: cpu-usage, task-manager

I've been having a recent problem lately with my CPU usage. It's literally always around 90%-100% but in task manager under 'user' it says differently. Even when I do a rough calculation of the processes, they don't add up to what task manager or performance monitor (Advanced System Care) says it is. What's going on?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) for a more detailed look into what could be causing the problem. Could you the post a screenshot of that here?-

Comment: @TheKB Updated, it's still showing an odd difference.

Comment: have you tried WPR/WPA? if you need help, share the generated ETL file

Comment: @magicandre1981 I updated the screenshot with what the generated ETL file looks like in WPA. I'm not sure what to look for. Even right now, my processes seem to stay between 20%-40% (as it always used to) when actually calculated. But nowadays, it's apparently higher than that. Even if everything that I have open is closed, it still spikes when there are no processes that are showing high usage. This is seriously frustrating.

Comment: you need to expand the stack column of SYSTEM as you can see in my posted picture

Comment: were you able to expand the stack column? Click on the arrow before SYSTEM and go to the stack column and also click on the arrow to expand the stack column

Comment: any update? Have you expanded the stack? Where you able to find the cause?

Answer (score 1):

The system process causes high CPU usage.

To diag the CPU usage issues, you should use Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) to capture **CPU Sampling** data (not precise, this is useful to detect hangs).

To capture the data, [install the Windows Performance Toolkit](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4847.install-the-windows-performance-toolkit-wpt.aspx), which is part of the [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk).

[image]

Now run `WPRUI.exe`, select `First Level`, under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**.

[image]

Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. After 1 minute click on **Save**.

Now [analyze the generated ETL file with the Windows Performance Analyzer](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis) by drag & drop the `CPU Usage (sampled)` graph to the `analysis pane` and order the colums like you see in the picture:

[image]

Inside WPA, [load the debug symbols](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx) and expand Stack of the SYSTEM process. In this demo, the CPU usage comes from the nVIDIA driver.