# High System CPU and interrupts when network I/O

Tags: networking, windows-10, drivers

When there is network activity on my computer (HP ZBook 15 G2) on Windows 10, it gets very hard to use due to interrupts/high CPU usage of the System process. The mouse is laggy, music gets crackly and so on. The ethernet adapter is an Intel I217-LM.

I traced the problem down to the `NdisAllocateBufferPool` function of the `ndis.sys` (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMbwI.png)). I updated the network driver, but the problem persists. The "Interrupt Moderation" function in the drivers settings are active, but that doesn't really make a difference.

Comment: capture a WPR trace and analyze it with WPA: http://superuser.com/a/1091414/174557

Comment: have you tried WPR/WPA to analyze it?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time yet... It seems to be caused by `NEOFLTR_819_45775.SYS`, part of the Pulse Secure Application Manager I use for VPN. It apparently also affects non-VPN connections.

Comment: ok. have you tried to update the software? If not, does removing fix it?

Answer (score 1):

In windows 10 there is a feature that downloads and shares updates on network from your PC.

You can turn it off by doing this.

1. Open settings and click update & security.
2. In Windows update click Advanced options and then click choose how updates are delivered.
3. Turn it off.